# Get entries filtered by author's category

Tags: entries, categories, author

I got a list of entries `news` (channel type).
They are created by `users` (or `author`).
These users have a category `region` assigned to them.

My point is to list the `news` entries that have the same `author's category` than the `currentUser's category`...

I am trying with relatedTo but I am stuck here:

```
{% if currentUser %}
    {% set userRegion = currentUser.region.first() %}
{% endif %}

{% set regionNews = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo('and',
    { sourceElement: currentUser, field: 'unepRegion' },
    { targetElement: author, field: 'unepRegion' }
) %}
```

Really don't know where I am going with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to query twice, first get all the users and then get all news entries
published by any of these users using the [`authorId`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#authorId) parameter on your criteria model.

```
{% set userRegion = currentUser.region.first() %}
{% set regionUsersIds = craft.users.relatedTo(userRegion).limit(null).ids() %}

{% set regionNews = craft.entries.section('news').authorId(regionUsersIds) %}
```

Comment: Genius! :D This idea arise in my head too when I woke this morning! :) Testing now... Tell you...

Comment: Worked like a charm :D Thx!